Installing Large Floating Shelves Over Small (Penny) Round Tiles
I would like to install wood floating shelves that are 5 foot over penny round tiles.  The tiles are glossy porcelain like these.
The floating shelves are similar to these and could store up to 90lbs.
We have 4 studs into which the brackets can be mounted.
The classic question is can I install over the tile?  Or do I need to tile first?  Certainly the former is easier and so my sense from researching this, is that with large tiles like subway tiles are it is fine to install over the tile.
I'm not sure if this intuition applies with these smaller tiles.  They're porcelain so they're relatively strong but they're smaller as well.  I suspect I can even install the mounting screws for the brackets in between the tiles themselves.
Appreciate any insight and recommendations.

The tiles are hard, but quite fragile.  I would go in between the tiles since grout is usually easier to drill into than tiles.  Do use the studs.

I have these types of brackets in my home.  If the grout lines line up, this is the way to go.  If not, you may need to plan ahead and leave tiles out where you need to hit studs with screws.

Thanks for the replies.  I realize that I wrote that incorrectly.  I was wondering if I could tile first and then install the bracket/shelves on top or should I install the brackets and then tile.

I would bracket first.  That way you are not limited by screw size(diameter) fitting into the grout line or grout line being in the centre of a stud.  The shelves can go tile since they are screwed just onto the brackets.
